# Wrong Convert amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following function works perfect, but when the amount over 1 million, the function don't work exactly.

Example: 
AMOUNTPAID = 35555
The output is: 35.555,00 - work fine

But when the amount paid is for example: 1223578 (over 1 Million),
is the output the following output value: 1.223.235,00 (but it must be: 1.223.578,00) - there is a deviation of 343

Any ideas?

I call the function via HTML as follows:

```
<td class="tr1 td2"><p class="p2 ft4"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(ConvertBetrag('{{NETAMOUNT}}'))</script> €</P></TD>
```

#

Here ist the Javascript:

```
function Convertamount( amount ){
        var number = amount;

        number = Math.round(number * Math.pow(12, 2)) / Math.pow(12, 2);
        number = number.toFixed(2);
        number = number.toString(); 

        var negative = false;
        if (number.indexOf("-") == 0)
        {
            negative = true ;
            number = number.replace("-",""); 
        }

        var str = number.toString();
        str = str.replace(".", ",");

        // number before decimal point
        var intbeforedecimaln = str.length - (str.length - str.indexOf(","));

        // number of delimiters
        var intKTrenner = Math.floor((intbeforedecimaln - 1) / 3);

        // Leading digits before the first dot
        var intZiffern = (intbeforedecimaln % 3 == 0) ? 3 : (intbeforedecimaln % 3);

        // Provided digits before the first thousand separator with point
        strNew = str.substring(0, intZiffern);

        // Auxiliary string without the previously treated digits
        strHelp = str.substr(intZiffern, (str.length - intZiffern));

        // Through thousands of remaining ...
        for(var i=0; i<intKTrenner; i++)
        {
            // attach 3 digits of the nearest thousand group point to String
            strNew += "." + strHelp.substring(0, 3);

            // Post new auxiliary string without the 3 digits being treated
            strHelp = strHelp.substr(intZiffern, (strHelp.length - intZiffern));
        }

        // attach a decimal
        var szdecimal = str.substring(intbeforedecimaln, str.length);
        if (szdecimal.length < 3 )
        {
            strNew += str.substring(intbeforedecimaln, str.length) + '0';
        }
        else
        {
            strNew += str.substring(intbeforedecimaln, str.length);
        }
        var number = strNew;

        if (negative)
        {
            number = "- " + number ;
        }

        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you multiply the number by 144, just to divide it by 144 (inside the rounding-op in line 4?)

Comment: @maze-le he rounds that value then divides it isn't exactly the same thing :( ... still why?

Comment: @Cayce K: Oh... my bad, I have ignored a paranthesis...

Comment: ah damn, its in the source code 10, 2. i translate into english, because im german dude ;-) it was my mistake by translate this script

Comment: even though he deleted his answer maybe getting that function from php.js would work. James answer would be good for you in Locale stuff. I'm in America so the `. ,` replacements are weird to me still.. Just a thought.

Comment: strHelp = strHelp.substr(intZiffern, (strHelp.length - intZiffern));   - This line is responsible for error : for the first time in for loop you are modifying strHelp and when control goes into the for loop 2nd time you are applying .substr method on modified strHelp, but not on the original strHelp.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript's `Math` functions have a [`toLocaleString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Why don't you just use this?

```
var n = (1223578.00).toLocaleString();
-> "1,223,578.00"
```

The locale you wish to use can be passed in as a parameter, for instance:

```
var n = (1223578.00).toLocaleString('de-DE');
-> "1.223.578,00"
```

Comment: .00 is not a fixxed value, it change often. Its for a booking stack report (example: 1. booking has the netamount: 214,15 ; the next hast 2.357,78 € and so on..

Comment: @user3652830 I've modified the answer to remove what I was doing with decimals. You can convert them this way as well. `(214.15).toLocaleString()`.

Comment: Hey James, it not work, i have placeholders, the placeholder where fill via sql. i can write in the report: <script type="text/javascript"> var neutest = ({{BETRAGGEZAHLT}}).toLocaleString('de-DE'); </script> and in the HTML: <td class="tr1 td1"><p class="p3 ft4"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(neutest)</script></P></TD>           but there is the output: 0.0

Comment: Without knowing what `{{BETRAGGEZAHLT}}` is I can't really help I'm afraid.

Comment: It's a automacially filled field (from sql)